# What technique is used in Bananatag Chrome extension to track email open

Tags: email, google-chrome-extension

I found this Chrome extension and very excited with this function.
I want to know how this extension can do this.
When I open mail sent by Bananatag extension, I can see in the last mail body image tag:

```
<img width="1" height="1" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/5BkS5ptzSiTydfw6u4E3DlXN_g1UedSoHoCr_57prqFqPgk-8WMa8ZhpYhK2G3tLgPCa=s0-d-e1-ft#http://s.bl-1.com/j3zT7Vt.gif" class="CToWUd">
```

I copy url in src property to the address bar of browser and enter.
In the Bananatag member page, it generate records here!.
How can this extension do that, this url is

```
ci3.googleusercontent.com
```

It's Google server, how it can get request from Google server?

Answer (score 1):

[Gmail loads images through a proxy](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html) so the URL you see is Google controlled but the image host will still register a hit.

Comment: That's horrifying as a default policy (showing images automatically), and is precisely why those trackers can function semi-reliably. Disgusting - even if opt-out is possible.

Comment: It adds some privacy around IP/useragent while removing some privacy around open rates. It depends on what one's privacy concern is.

Comment: Opt-out is best of both worlds though. Have the images load up after a confirmation, through the proxy.